# How to add data in history table with triggers only when it contains changes

Tags: mysql, triggers

There is a python script that updates data in MySQL table. The problem is that when no changes has been made in data, trigger makes duplicate of every record in history_table.

```
create trigger organizations_history_update after update on organizations for each row 
begin

declare N DATE;
set N = now();

UPDATE organizations_history
SET EndDate = N
WHERE id = OLD.id
AND EndDate IS NULL;

insert into organizations_history (id, name,current_version, db_maintenance_plan, custom_localization, custom_skin_for_ipad, custom_server_version, zendesk_id, StartDate, EndDate)
values (new.id, new.name, new.current_version, new.db_maintenance_plan, new.custom_localization, new.custom_skin_for_ipad, new.custom_server_version, new.zendesk_id, N, NULL);
end;
```

Comment: If you only want to conditionally insert to organizations_history then test OLD vs NEW columns to see if something has changed

Comment: Also I'm a bit unclear how you would have an update which doesn't update anything.

Comment: I have 46 rows in the main table. Firstly running the script with the same data, I get the 46 rows in history_table. After second running the script I get 92 rows in history_table, after third initiation of script I get 138 and so on..

Comment: Triggers will fire on an update even if no columns are updated. Your update script must be hitting 46 rows each time..It;s up to you to test (IF..THEN..END IF) if the insert should happen. For this questions purpose you could cut the numbers down to something more manageable (3 say) and publish sample data together with your script.

Comment: Thx. I'll try to mix something up with (if..then..end if) statements.